# Filter multidimensional array based on input angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a `primeng p-table` component in which its `(onChange)` event I call my own function `filterData()` which I pass in the $event, p-table, and column of the table. Inside `filterData` I call the `filter` function which is a built in function for `p-table` like so:

```
dt.filter(event.value, 'column1', 'equals'); //dt is the ID of the p-table component
```

The built in `filter()` function does not return anything.

In this component I also have a button which exports the contents of the `p-table` to excel. The only problem is that it only exports the entire contents of the `p-table`. I need it to export based on what is filtered.

Since the built in `filter()` function doesn't return anything, how can I easily get the filtered data to pass to my logic to populate my excel? Or better yet, how can I access the filtered data directly?

My original data is:

```
subs: Sub[]; //the array I want to filter on

Sub {
    id: number;
    cont: Cont; //custom object type
    type: Type; //custom object type
    gen: Gen; //custom object type
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sources (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts), the `filter()` function updates a public `filteredValue` field you should be able to access:

```
<button type="button" pButton label="Export"
        (click)="onExportClick(dt.filteredValue, $event)"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. `dt.filteredValue` is simply the filtered version of the array used to populate the table.